# MVC Post Value Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I have been searching for this but I cannot seem to find an answer on why its happening. I think that if I can understand why this is happening I can prevent it in the future.

So I have a basic Edit View that looks something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>EditUserViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username,  new { @class = "form-control",disabled="disabled"} )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName,"First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control -label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "Phone Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Role, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role, new SelectList(@Model.Roles, Model.Role),  new { @class = "form-control" } )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Partial("_SaveButtons", new SaveButtonsViewModel("Admin","Index", ""))
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Please note that I added the Item in question(Username) after I created the View.

so when I go to click "Save" and it does a Post, the username is always null. I Started looking into this and I noticed that it isn't in the form data:

[image]

So now my question, why would this not be added to the form when it is inside the form, and I am using @Html helper methods?

Comment: **1.** Because it's `disabled`, it isn't part of the form data. **2.** Do you really want your client to determine the `Role` of the user?

Comment: 1, so because its disabled it will not be part of the form? 2: I do want the admin to be able to edit the role of the user, why wouldn't I want that?

Comment: **1.** Yes. **2.** In this case I assume it's fine.

Comment: Input element with `disabled` attribute will not send as form data, hence you should use `readonly` instead: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username,  new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `input` element which has `disabled` attribute enabled will not be submitted as part of form data, which mentioned in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled):

> `disabled`
>
> Indicates whether the element is disabled or not. If this attribute is
>   set, the element is disabled. Disabled elements are usually drawn with
>   grayed-out text. If the element is disabled, it does not respond to
>   user actions, it cannot be focused, and the command event will not
>   fire. **In the case of form elements, it will not be submitted.**

If you want to prevent user input but the existing value inside textbox will be sent together in form submit, use `readonly` attribute instead:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Since `readonly` is part of [C# keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/), you need to use `@` prefix to escape it as HTML attribute. Note that you can stylize `readonly` element to look like disabled input by using CSS.